# Windows 2003 DNS TSIG transfer?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, bind, keys

I am trying to use a Windows 2003 R2 server as a secondary dns server for my BIND 9 master. The problem is I use keys to control transfers and I dont know how to add the key to Windows so its able to copy the zone files from the master.

I saw a TechNet article about enabling DNSSEC which I also need.

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

Windows and Windows Server's DNS Server only support GSS-TSIG
BIND only supports MD5-TSIG. They're not compatible.

Comment: Dang it! That is what I was afraid of, oh well looks like I will have to setup another Linux box and install BIND on it. Thanks.